# Javascript quiz errors. Quiz questions no longer displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, javascript-objects

I am working on a javascript, html based quiz for a uni project. I have to rework it as it was not responsive as i put it all on a single page that was 200% width and used current tags and opacity to hide and display the quiz. I have remade it to 2 pages, index and quiz pages. I haven't started on the media queries just trying to get it working, i cant use bootstrap as well as i made this around 6 months ago. There are no console errors, or anything that sticks out.

[Preview working code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djcave/gn85xo3k/1/)

```
const continueBtn = document.querySelector('.continue-btn');
const quizSection = document.querySelector('.quiz-section');
const quizBox = document.querySelector('.quiz-box');
const resultBox = document.querySelector('.result-box');
const tryAgainBtn = document.querySelector('.try-again-btn');
const homeBtn = document.querySelector('.home-button');

// Try again onclick current tag target and reset counters for user to try quiz again
tryAgainBtn.onclick = () => {
    quizBox.classList.add('current');
    nextBtn.classList.remove('current');
    resultBox.classList.remove('current');

    questionCount = 0;
    questionNumb = 1;
    userScore = 0;
    showQuestions(questionCount);
    quizCounter(questionNumb);
    headerScore();
};

// Homepage button targetting for current tag
homeBtn.onclick = () => {
    quizSection.classList.remove('current');
    nextBtn.classList.remove('current');
    resultBox.classList.remove('current');

    questionCount = 0;
    questionNumb = 1;
    userScore = 0;
    showQuestions(questionCount);
    quizCounter(questionNumb);
};

// Display Question counter as 0
let questionCount = 0;
// Display Number of Questions Beggining with 1
let questionNumb = 1;
// Display user score as begginer 0
let userScore = 0;

const quizQuestions = document.querySelector('.quiz-questions');

// Function to show each question and targets array in questions.js
function showQuestions(i) {
    const questionText = document.querySelector('.question-title');
    questionText.textContent = `${questions[i].numb}. ${questions[i].question}`;

    let quizTag = `<div class="question"><span>${questions[i].options[0]}</span></div>
    <div class="question"><span>${questions[i].options[1]}</span></div>
    <div class="question"><span>${questions[i].options[2]}</span></div>
    <div class="question"><span>${questions[i].options[3]}</span></div>`;

    quizQuestions.innerHTML = quizTag;

    const question = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
    for (let i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
        question[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'questionSelected(this)');
    }
}

// Function to display correct or incorrect answer selected
function questionSelected(answer) {
    let userAnswer = answer.textContent;
    let correctAnswer = questions[questionCount].answer;
    let allQuestions = quizQuestions.children.length;

    if (userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        answer.classList.add('correct');
        userScore += 1;
        headerScore();
    } else {

        answer.classList.add('incorrect');
        for (let i = 0; i < allQuestions; i++) {
            if (quizQuestions.children[i].textContent == correctAnswer) {
                quizQuestions.children[i].setAttribute('class', 'question correct');
            }
        }
    }
    // Add disable tag for question childeren
    for (let i = 0; i < allQuestions; i++) {
        quizQuestions.children[i].classList.add('disabled');
    }

    nextBtn.classList.add('current');
}

const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');

// Next question button
nextBtn.onclick = () => {
    if (questionCount < questions.length - 1) {
        questionCount++;
        showQuestions(questionCount);
        questionNumb++;
        quizCounter(questionNumb);
        nextBtn.classList.remove('current');
    } else {
        showResultBox();
    }
};

// Function to count quiz question
function quizCounter(i) {
    const quizTotal = document.querySelector('.quiz-total');
    quizTotal.textContent = `${i} of ${questions.length} Questions`;
}

// Function to display user score in header
function headerScore() {
    const headerScoreText = document.querySelector('.header-score');
    headerScoreText.textContent = `Score ${userScore} / ${questions.length}`;
}

// Function to display user score in results
function showResultBox() {
    quizBox.classList.remove('current');
    resultBox.classList.add('current');

    const scoreText = document.querySelector('.score-text');
    scoreText.textContent = `You Scored ${userScore} Out Of ${questions.length}`;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>InPhysical Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="quiz-section">
        <!-- Quiz Box holds code for each question -->
        <div class="quiz-box">
            <!-- Page Header -->
            <h2>InPhysical Quiz!</h2>
            <!-- Quiz Title -->
            <div class="quiz-header">
                <span>Fitness and Exercise Quiz</span>
                <!-- Heading score for the quiz -->
                <span class="header-score">Score 0 / 5</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Quiz question -->
            <h2 class="question-title">When squatting which muscle is not used?</h2>
            <!-- Div Class holding quiz question answers -->
            <div class="quiz-questions"></div>
            <!-- Quiz Footer -->
            <div class="quiz-footer">
                <!-- Quiz Question counter -->
                <span class="quiz-total">1 of 5 Questions</span>
                <!-- Next button for nex quiz question -->
                <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- HTML for quiz results -->
        <div class="result-box">
            <!-- Quiz result title -->
            <h2>Quiz Results!</h2>
            <!-- Quiz results container -->
            <div class="results-container">
                <!-- Shows user score -->
                <span class="score-text">You Scored 0 Out Of 5</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Try again and Home buttom for user -->
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="try-again-btn">Try Again!</button>
                <button class="home-button">Home</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<!-- Script link for quiz questions -->
<script defer src="assets/js/questions.js"></script>
<!-- Main script code for quiz -->
<script defer src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Example of questions array

```
let questions = [{
    numb: 1,
    question: 'When squatting which muscle is not used?',
    answer: 'D. Biceps',
    options: [
        'A. Glutes',
        'B. Quads',
        'C. Hamstrings',
        'D. Biceps',
    ]
},
{
    numb: 2,
    question: 'Which exercise targets the lats when working out?',
    answer: 'D. Cable Pull Down',
    options: [
        'A. Hyperextensions',
        'B. Overhead Press',
        'C. Box Squats',
        'D. Cable Pull Down',
    ]
},
```

Originally the html was all on a single page, it was set to 200% and used current/active tags along with transitions to hide the quiz part. then onclick button it would hide the info page and then the quiz would slide over and user can fill out the 5 questions and would provide a score and option to try again, which would reset the score and allow user to start again. all the questions are listen in questions.js and shown a preview about.

The code before would add itself and then after each question click next and then it would display the next. I know there are probably better ways to make a quiz app but I'm seeing if that if its best to rewrite the quiz functions and start again or try to make this work.

Comment: In your `showQuestions` function, you're overwriting the innerHTML of `quizQuestions` in each iteration of the loop, only leaving the last question. Instead, append each question to the existing content.

Comment: Let's focus this question. Please name your greatest problem that you currently have. Because currently the problem-statement is "I have this old code that's not working and I would like to resolve some problems". But this is too vague currently.

Comment: Okay, So my main and only problem is currently I cannot get my questions for the quiz to display. On my previous version of the site, I had no problems and all working. once I separated the pages to make it easier to make them responsive, I cannot get my questions to display on the page. I have checked jshint and says my questions variable is not defined so I included the questions array into the script file. But still no look, took CodexPro advice to try and append each question but not sure how and researching that currently. Hope that is more specific and apologies.

Comment: Okay. So you had an earlier version that worked and you are trying to refactor it. Can you create a fiddle with your old version as well so I could get an idea of how the questions are to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, i have copied all the code from the old repo and uploaded here [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/djcave/rv9ywbna/6/) will need to make the view part larger as I made it fitting the screen of laptop but didn't get round to media queries for responsiveness, hence why I decided to move to a new page and remove the transitions. but can see it working there correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call `showQuestions` and pass the index of the question you want to show, like

```
showQuestions(0);
```

You also need to have `questions` in the first place, so let's define them:

```
let questions = [
    {
       options: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
       numb: 1,
       question: "huh?"
    },
    {
       options: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"],
       numb: 2,
       question: "huhhuhu?"
    },
    {
       options: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"],
       numb: 3,
       question: "com' on, man?"
    },
];
```

The above is just dummy data, it's your responsibility to make sure those values are proper. But from the way things are used, we can see that `questions` must be an array, whose elements are objects and each such objects have an `options` array as a field, a `numb` field representing the question number to be displayed and a question text. I have modified only your Javascript to this:

```
const continueBtn = document.querySelector('.continue-btn');
const quizSection = document.querySelector('.quiz-section');
const quizBox = document.querySelector('.quiz-box');
const resultBox = document.querySelector('.result-box');
const tryAgainBtn = document.querySelector('.try-again-btn');
const homeBtn = document.querySelector('.home-button');

// Try again onclick current tag target and reset counters for user to try quiz again
tryAgainBtn.onclick = () => {
    quizBox.classList.add('current');
    nextBtn.classList.remove('current');
    resultBox.classList.remove('current');

    questionCount = 0;
    questionNumb = 1;
    userScore = 0;
    showQuestions(questionCount);
    quizCounter(questionNumb);
    headerScore();
};

// Homepage button targetting for current tag
homeBtn.onclick = () => {
    quizSection.classList.remove('current');
    nextBtn.classList.remove('current');
    resultBox.classList.remove('current');

    questionCount = 0;
    questionNumb = 1;
    userScore = 0;
    showQuestions(questionCount);
    quizCounter(questionNumb);
};

// Display Question counter as 0
let questionCount = 0;
// Display Number of Questions Beggining with 1
let questionNumb = 1;
// Display user score as begginer 0
let userScore = 0;

const quizQuestions = document.querySelector('.quiz-questions');

let questions = [
    {
       options: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
       numb: 1,
       question: "huh?"
    },
    {
       options: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"],
       numb: 2,
       question: "huhhuhu?"
    },
    {
       options: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"],
       numb: 3,
       question: "com' on, man?"
    },
];

// Function to show each question and targets array in questions.js
function showQuestions(i) {
    const questionText = document.querySelector('.question-title');
    questionText.textContent = `${questions[i].numb}. ${questions[i].question}`;

    let quizTag = `<div class="question"><span>${questions[i].options[0]}</span></div>
    <div class="question"><span>${questions[i].options[1]}</span></div>
    <div class="question"><span>${questions[i].options[2]}</span></div>
    <div class="question"><span>${questions[i].options[3]}</span></div>`;

    quizQuestions.innerHTML = quizTag;

    const question = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
    for (let i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
        question[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'questionSelected(this)');
    }
}

// Function to display correct or incorrect answer selected
function questionSelected(answer) {
    let userAnswer = answer.textContent;
    let correctAnswer = questions[questionCount].answer;
    let allQuestions = quizQuestions.children.length;

    if (userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        answer.classList.add('correct');
        userScore += 1;
        headerScore();
    } else {

        answer.classList.add('incorrect');
        for (let i = 0; i < allQuestions; i++) {
            if (quizQuestions.children[i].textContent == correctAnswer) {
                quizQuestions.children[i].setAttribute('class', 'question correct');
            }
        }
    }
    // Add disable tag for question childeren
    for (let i = 0; i < allQuestions; i++) {
        quizQuestions.children[i].classList.add('disabled');
    }

    nextBtn.classList.add('current');
}

const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');

// Next question button
nextBtn.onclick = () => {
    if (questionCount < questions.length - 1) {
        questionCount++;
        showQuestions(questionCount);
        questionNumb++;
        quizCounter(questionNumb);
        nextBtn.classList.remove('current');
    } else {
        showResultBox();
    }
};

// Function to count quiz question
function quizCounter(i) {
    const quizTotal = document.querySelector('.quiz-total');
    quizTotal.textContent = `${i} of ${questions.length} Questions`;
}

// Function to display user score in header
function headerScore() {
    const headerScoreText = document.querySelector('.header-score');
    headerScoreText.textContent = `Score ${userScore} / ${questions.length}`;
}

// Function to display user score in results
function showResultBox() {
    quizBox.classList.remove('current');
    resultBox.classList.add('current');

    const scoreText = document.querySelector('.score-text');
    scoreText.textContent = `You Scored ${userScore} Out Of ${questions.length}`;
}

showQuestions(0);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0bze513t/1/

And this is how it looks alike to me:

[image]

Comment: Hi Lajos so all working now, just had to actually show the questions, so sorry, added the ShowQuestions to the bottom and they all showed up perfectly. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: @DJCave please don't be sorry. On this site we, fellow programmers help each-other when a technical problem arises. We just need to make sure that the question is focused so we can address it. I'm glad it now works, happy new year!

Comment: Thank you very much, Looking back at the code I can see now that I had a onclick event for the continue button that would add current tags to show the quiz and have it slide over but it also contained showQuestion(0) so that would make the questions show up. But only found out until I saw what you put so thank you again and when need some help in future will be as specific as possible, newer to software so didn't really know how to ask, Happy new year to yourself :)